# Is it possible to create CDImage having both “.cab” and “folder structure”

Tags: wix, wix3.6

My requirement is create a CDImage having source files packed in both cab and folder structure

I followed the below steps:

```
<Package Compressed='yes' ... />

<Media Id='1' Cabinet='Com~1.cab' Layout='Program Files\Common Files\System' />
```

By this I able to create folder structure hierarchy and Com~1.cab file. But my installation does not work. MSI looking for the file at location next to the .msi instead of under `Program Files\Common Files\System`.

Can anyone help how to resolve my issue and please let me know if any more information required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to decide if you want the files in your MSI compressed or not. You can actually mix some compressed files with some uncompressed files but that ends up usually more complicated than it is worth.

If you want compressed, set the `Package/@Compressed='yes'` and the `Media/@Cabinet='something'` or use `MediaTemplate`. Then make sure your File elements do not specify `Compressed='no'` (unless you want some specific files uncompressed, as noted above this is unusual).

Comment: I want the files to be both compressed and uncompressed in my MSI.

Comment: Please let me know how create uncompressed file shoud be packed with folder structure hierarchy in Package/@Compressed='yes' project. I created like below then installkit is coming like as expected but installation is failing. Package/@Compressed='yes' , <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Com~1.cab" DiskPrompt="1" VolumeLabel="DISK1" />, <Media Id="2" DiskPrompt="1" Layout="Program Files\Common Files\System" VolumeLabel="DISK1" /> and <File Id="xx.bat" Compressed="no" DiskId="2"  Source="!(bindpath.xx)\xx.bat" /> & <File Id="xxx.bat" Compressed="yes" DiskId="1"  Source=".\xxx.bat" />

Comment: Ahh, `Media/@Layout` attribute is used for very special scenarios. It helps group .cab files into different folders to make it easier to burn CDs. However, when using it, the result is an image that *will not* install. Remove the `Media/@Layout` attributes and I expect you'll start seeing things work.

Comment: Thanks Rob,

It's installing successfully when I removed layout in media  <Media Id="2" DiskPrompt="1" VolumeLabel="DISK1" />  and let me know is it possible to create folder for these uncompressed files in Media/@Id=”2” or not.

Comment: You can mark individual `File` elements as `Compressed='no'` then place them on `DiskId='2'` if you like. I've never seen anyone do that.

Comment: Even that the file is not going to folder. It packed at .msi location only. yes Rob its not standard process but my client requested like the same image which is there in my previous tool :)

Comment: That's correct. The uncompressed files will end up next to the .msi file if the .msi package is marked compressed. You can try marking the `Package/@Compressed='no'` and then explicitly mark the files you want compressed. You are bound by the Windows Installer functionality.

Comment: Thank's Rob, It's working perfect after marking the Package/@Compressed='no' and then explicitly marked the files I want compressed(Merge/@ FileCompression="yes" and File/@compressed=yes).